# Bootstrap dropdown menu works only once

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This has got to be something simple, but I cannot figure out how to correct it. I am using the Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu CSS and JS.

The problem: I click the dropdown menu, it works. I select a link from the dropdown menu and when it takes me to that page, the dropdown menu does not work on that page.

The dropdown menu only works for 1 time.

HTML in application.html.erb:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">   
      <li class="dropdown">  
        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-pages" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <a href="#" id="pages" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a></div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pages"> 
          <li><%= link_to("Contacts", contacts_path) %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

JS & jQuery are loaded in application.html.erb:

```
   <!-- jQuery & Javascript CDN Includes -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It seems like the JS or jQuery needed for the action doesn't reload on page change.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:  JS Code

```
+function ($) { "use strict";

  // DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var backdrop = '.dropdown-backdrop'
  var toggle   = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
  var Dropdown = function (element) {
    var $el = $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    clearMenus()

    if (!isActive) {
      if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
        // if mobile we we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
        $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
      }

      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown'))

      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

      $parent
        .toggleClass('open')
        .trigger('shown.bs.dropdown')

      $this.focus()
    }

    return false
  }

  Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (!/(38|40|27)/.test(e.keyCode)) return

    var $this = $(this)

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    if (!isActive || (isActive && e.keyCode == 27)) {
      if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).focus()
      return $this.click()
    }

    var $items = $('[role=menu] li:not(.divider):visible a', $parent)

    if (!$items.length) return

    var index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))

    if (e.keyCode == 38 && index > 0)                 index--                        // up
    if (e.keyCode == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
    if (!~index)                                      index=0

    $items.eq(index).focus()
  }

  function clearMenus() {
    $(backdrop).remove()
    $(toggle).each(function (e) {
      var $parent = getParent($(this))
      if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return
      $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown'))
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return
      $parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown')
    })
  }

  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector)

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
  }


  // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  var old = $.fn.dropdown

  $.fn.dropdown = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('dropdown')

      if (!data) $this.data('dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


  // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }


  // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
  // ===================================

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
    .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
    .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: can you post the js include code?

Comment: Sure, just posted it.

Comment: So that I'm not confused, it only works on the index page? Or if you load any page, then it will only work once? So if you were to reload any page over and over again it will always work the first time?

Comment: also, I'm not sure why you are including JS in application.html.erb. Did you install bootstrap by gem? If so, it is or probably should be //require bootstrap in your application.js file. And then it will be yielded in the application file. Also, are you using less or sass version?

Comment: Yes, the functionality only works on the index page - no other page. If I reload the index page, yes, it will work over and over.

Comment: I am using bootstrap but via CDN, not the gem. I removed the include for application.js. Forgot it was even there.

Answer (score 3):

Blah - scraped the CDN for bootstrap JS and went local with it. Dropdown now works on all pages.

Something must have been happening where the CDN wasn't being loaded within subpages.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same issue. Including the bootstrap JS file on every html worked for me as well. thanks!